# flag controlled loop eof loop

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to write a C++ program which reads numbers from a file and display their total and maximum on the screen.
The program should stop if one or more of the conditions given below become true:
1.  The total has exceeded 5555.
2.  The end of file has been reached.
Note I MUST use both end-of-file and flag control while loops to solve this problem.

> **SAMPLE INPUT**
>   1000  2500
>   1500    1100
>   3300    1200
>
> the output should be 
>   6100
>   2500
>
> the output i get : 
>   7500
>   2500

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
   ifstream infile;
   ofstream outfile;
   int num;
   int sum=0;
   int max=0;
   bool found=false;

   infile.open("Input.txt");
   outfile.open("output.txt");

   if(!infile)
      cout<<"File Can not open \n";
   else
   {
      infile>>num;
      while(!infile.eof())
      {
         infile>>num;
         while(!found)
         {
            if(num>=max)
               max=num;
            sum+=num;
            if(sum>=5555)
               found=true;

         }
      }
   }
   outfile<<sum<<endl; 
   outfile<<max<<endl; 
   infile.close();
   outfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small problem in your program. The first number being read is not used to compute the sum.

```
  infile>>num;   // The first number. Read and not used.
  while(!infile.eof())
  {
     infile>>num; // The second number and subsequent numbers.
```

You can use one `while` loop instead of two and fix the problem also by using:

```
  while( sum < 5555 && (infile >> num) )
  {
     if(num>=max)
        max=num;
     sum+=num;
  }
```

You don't need the `found` variable either.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that the use of `while(!in.eof())` is a common mistake, because you need to check for success **after** trying to read something, not before.